# How to real-time update (or set) different jsp attributes in servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

My JSP has several different attributes which I have to set during execution.

```
getFormData(request);

if(formInfo.get("Type").equals("type1"))
    request.setAttribute("heading", "type1");
else
    request.setAttribute("heading", "type2");

request.setAttribute("loader", "<div class=\"loader\" id=\"loading_spinner\"></div>");
request.getRequestDispatcher("").forward(request, response);


FormValidator formValidator = new FormValidator(formInfo, request, response);
if(!formValidator.validateForm())
{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("").forward(request, response);
    return;
}

function(); //this function has soap call and can take few minutes.

if(success)           //assume success is boolean from function()
{
        System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        request.setAttribute("loader", "");
        request.setAttribute("error_message", "<h1 class=\"header-success\"> SUCCESS</h1>");
}
```

Now this has 2 problems.

1. If anyone (i.e. first) of the RequestDispatcher executes then others do not. `IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed.`
2. As function() takes a few minutes till that function is not done(),
   nothing gets updated on screen, not even the first attributes although it's RequestDispatcher has executed. after function() gets fully executed only then any update is visible on the screen.

I need the update to take place right at the time and in the order, I have coded.